# Set a specific password for sudo

Tags: passwords, sudo, root

Would it be possible to set a password different from the user one and the root one?

I find that asking for the user password kind of useless and the root one, even more, just give him the root login in that case...

Answer (score 0):

doing sudo is to give root permission to user. so it would be root password

Comment: I can use sudo without root even being enabled, so idk how you figure that out. It uses user password.

Comment: then does your line start with # or $?

Comment: $ until I sudo, then # until I exit

Comment: remove the last line and put it in /etc/sudoers.d/sudo-jupiter. Now revert back permissions on /etc/sudoers to u-x and restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly a result of a configuration in your sudoers file in which you can mandate that in order to elevate with sudo an alternative account password is required. Root being the obvious password to require. You are not limited to root however.

The sudoers configuration file dictates the behavior and elevation requirements for execution of commands and login rules when:

- *Prefixing the command with sudo*
- *or using ">$sudo su" - Elevate commands until "exit" is entered*

For example, currently in Ubuntu 22 you can manually edit the **/etc/sudoers** file to change these  rules.

However it is not recommended to manually edit this file as the smallest typographical or syntactical error can invalidate this file and cause the sudo behavior to ignore the file altogether.

For this reason, you should use a command line utility that is available called **visudo**